# Correct format for DateTime.ParseExact when the time is in hh:mmtt format

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert time string into a DateTime variable but it throws me an invalid time string exception. Can you please explain what is the problem and how to fix it ?

Here is my code:

```
string tmp = "1:30am";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(tmp, "hh:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: 1:30am of which date?

Comment: you need `h:mmtt` or a leading zero on the 1 e.g. `01:30am`. "hh" means 12-hour clock with leading zero. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: One small correction needed: tmp must be in uppercase so use tmp.ToUpper()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `h:mmtt` if `1:30` is allowed as opposed to `01:30`, `hh` is from 01 through 12:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(tmp, "h:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#hSpecifier

Comment: So did I, until he beat my answer by two keystrokes ; )

Comment: Thanks Tim. You saved some hours for me !

Comment: Hah took some time to find out how to accept. Done :D